# Video/image glitch in Rails App on page change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, video, refresh

I'm experiencing a weird glitch in my rails app located here: https://tcndapp.herokuapp.com/

My home page has a video background on it that loads correctly initially, but I'm facing an issue where when I go to a separate page (like the about page for instance) and then return the homepage, the video doesn't load, and it actually loads and displays the wide background image from the previous page, and then if I do a hard refresh then the video will load like normally, and that seems to be the only way to fix it.  I have the video linked as so in my index page and have tried using a video_tag instead with no luck.  This behavior also occurs both in production and development mode.

```
<video preload="true" autoplay loop muted playsinline>
   <source src="<%= image_url('main.webm') %>" type="video/webm">
    <source src="<%= image_url('main.mp4') %>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Are you using Turbolinks? It looks like it based on some of the markup, but just confirming.

Comment: @MattMcClure upon inspection I am using turbolinks.  I disabled them by removing the gem from my Gemfile.  This seems to have fixed the issue when running the app locally, however in production the problem still persists.

Comment: Nevermind, forgot to precompile my assets again, removing turboklinks did the fix! :)

Comment: Great! Glad to hear you got it working :)